# Excel 2013 Complete Decimals Needed

Tags: java, excel, excel-2013

In an excel, I entered a number with 50 decimal places.

(eg. `0.01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789`)

But when I hit on enter key, the cell displayed on 10 decimals

`0.0123456789`

I selected the cell and the formula bar only displays 16 decimals

`0.0123456789012345`

When I format the cell to Number with 30 decimal places, because this was the max, the cell now display the original 16 decimals with 14 trailing zeroes

`0.0123456789012345000000000000000`

I saved the excel to CSV format but still it only display 10 decimals

`0.0123456789`

Tried to extract it using java, and yes, it displayed the complete 50 decimals

If java can extract the original data, then **(1)** how will I display in excel the original data?
**(2)** how will I save it to CSV with the complete decimals

*I only placed 2013 because that's the version I am using, not sure if this scenario applies to other version*

Comment: Can you provide more info regarding how you went about extracting the data using Java?

Comment: I use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/) for Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the data still exists in storage, where Java can access and manipulate it, but the Excel program itself is restricted to 16 decimal point precision by Microsoft. You can read more about it in the following two links.

[Similar question, answered](https://superuser.com/questions/437764/why-is-excel-truncating-my-16-digit-numbers)

[Microsoft explaining inability to handle large decimals](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113)

Answer (score 0):

To save all digits to CSV, treat the data as text. That way you can have more than 16 digits, even though Excel will not treat that as numeric data.

Comment: Then you're not treating the values as text. Excel will leave text alone.